# Efficiency of high-voltage power lines

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current

If it is more efficient to have high voltage, low current power lines,  why aren't homes and appliances adapted to accept high voltage and low current (and remove the need for transformers)?

Comment: What sort of insulation would you propose? How would you design a power socket which wouldn't arc over directly between  its contacts?

Comment: I doubt I implied that I was sitting on top of high-tech insulation idea that I've yet to patent.  I'm studying to be an electrician and I was seeking information from those in the EE field to see the scientific barriers for high voltage/low current usage in residents/industry.  I thought maybe there were reasons involving circuits (something the EE field studies more) or laws of physics (something EE also studies more).  I'll let it go because I definitely want you guys to be willing to answer future questions because I'm very interested in EE as well (esp. in regards to sustainable energy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In designing high tension lines, the safe distance between conductors is 11..17 feet for the common 500..900kV lines.

To have an 'appliance' that operated directly off high tension would first off require an outlet and plug that were more than 14 feet wide, plus an additional 14 feet clearance on both sides for the user's safety (totaling 42 foot wide x 28 feet high for single phase; 42 foot high for 3-phase). Regardless of the strength of dielectrics, how would you plug and unplug something without exposing the conductors to air?

Designing an appliance runs into the same problem.  The load must be stretched out across the 14 feet to avoid arc-over. Be it a heating element or a motor. You would need bread 14 feet wide for such a toaster. Such a motor would necessarily be obscenely huge, maybe a 100 feet huge, because each winding must begin and end at least 14 feet apart. A 4 pole motor must have a circumference of at least 8*14 feet. The original generators at the power plant put out 28000 volts, and they cannot be made any smaller than the winding depth limits due to voltage generated in them. This is a good foot of depth to each coil. Minimally, there are 4 coils.  This size would go up 30-fold with a 30-fold voltage increase to 600,000 vac.

In addition to the scale of things being out of whack, there is the fact of electron inertia. They don't weigh much, but 100 miles of high tension current cannot stop instantly.  Break open a switch and they pour out as arc-over, jacob's ladder, and ball lightning. Without the isolating effects of a transformer, every kitchen worker would be at constant risk of such lethal surges.  Many a good electrician (good but not excellent) has met his death to such surges.

And if all of that is not enough, there is the 4th state of matter: plasma.  When electrons are forced (by their own inertia), to make their way without a conductor (metal); they get very irritated, let's say HOT.  They emit a lot of photons, at about 30,000 degrees F. It can cut right through living tissue the thickness of your thigh in a millisecond, perhaps nanoseconds. Its called cauderizing -and is very disturbing to witness, less alone be the victim of.

Comment: Thank you.  So arcing is the main issue.  You have a great way of describing things!

Comment: @ricardo breaking the comment into paragraphs made for an easier read.

Answer (score 4):

The high voltages used in power distribution are much more hazardous than the 120 or 240 volts we currently have in our homes.  They also require much better (thicker) insulation than lower voltages.

Around here, I think the local high voltage distribution is 12,000 volts.  Most local power distribution here is overhead, so we can see the high voltage lines at the very top of the power poles, on large insulators.  When the power company technicians have to work on the high voltage lines, they keep well away from the lines, using insulated "hot sticks" to manipulate the wires and fittings.  You don't want that sort of voltage wandering aroudn the average home!

Comment: It may be worth noting that when working with high voltages (more than 480 or so) it is not sufficient to avoid *touching* energized circuits.  Depend upon the voltage, coming within a few inches may be enough to give someone a lethal shock.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a more scientific answer.  Technological innovation takes care of safety concerns for most anything that has an end result of higher efficiency (think nuclear power plant).  One could easily argue that the high current, low voltage of a home is extremely dangerous.

Comment: There is an insurmountable technological problem with using high voltage (12KV or more) in the home - the cable insulation must be quite thick to safely handle the high voltage (or to prevent arcing between the supply wires), so the power cord for your table lamp would have to be the size of a fire hose - not really practical.  And I don't want to think about the problems of circuit breakers, and wiring through the walls of the house.

Comment: What I'm hearing is that modern-day insulation has not been developed to adapt to high voltage supplies for the circular logic that high voltage residential wiring simply doesn't exist and so there is no demand and accompanying technological innovation for lightweight, non-voluminous insulation.

Answer (score 3):

Two main reasons

Safety.

Cost and size of insulation.

When you're moving around 100s of MW, particularly for long distance, it makes sense to use a high voltage and pay for the relatively large infrastructure needed to deal with the high voltage.  The towers that hold high voltage power lines are big for a reason.  The cheapest way to insulate long high voltage transmission lines is to keep a lot of air between them and everything else.

In underground cables, creating that kind of space around each conductor would require large and vastly expensive tunnels, so insulation becomes cheaper.  Even so, that insulation needs to be thick, and there is a conducting grounded sheath around the cable to bleed off the leakage that does make it thru the insulation.  All that is expensive.  Underground cables are both more expensive to install and to maintain the overhead power lines.

In a house, there is not enough space to use air insulation, so expensive, heavy, and bulky insulating materials would need to be used.  And, this doesn't end with the wires in the walls.  Outlets would have to be actively insulated somehow to prevent arcing, and worst of all, all appliances would need to be insulated for the high voltage.  Do you really want a hair dryer that is the size of a breadbox, has a 6 inch diameter line cord that weighs 30 pounds, and costs $10k?  Yes, the actualy power-carrying wire can be very small because it only has to carry 150 mA at 13.8 kV instead of 17 A at 120 V, but all the infrastructure to deal with the high voltage swamps that savings.  And, 13.8 kV is still a rather low voltage.  That's what goes to the transformer on the power pole in front of my house, and is used for distribution in our town.  The feed into town comes from much larger power lines at 100s of kV.

Comment: The logic concerning appliance size seems to be assuming that the status quo is the only acceptable method and working one's way back to defend it.  I am certain that if high voltage, low current were the only option for residential wiring then technology would have been adapted to make it so a hair dryer doesn't weigh ton and cost $10,000.  I'd wager that insulation technology would simply be better.

Comment: @Mount: There are plenty of other reasons people have been and are working on insulation technology.  It simply isn't that easy.  If the power company didn't have to spring for a transformer every house or ever few houses, they'd save money.  Voltage is brought down for houses for lots of very good reasons.  If you weren't going to believe any of the answers, then why did you bother asking the question?

Comment: getting personal.  trying to keep it scientific.  "plenty of other reasons" is a dodge. sorry if I offended you.

Answer (score 2):

Power lines that have high voltage are done so because the \$I^2R\$ losses over many miles of feed are reduced to an acceptable level. Once the electricity reaches the end of the street, a typical house (including all the internal wires to the furthest socket) is probably a few hundred feet max therefore the economics of feeding high voltage cable to the house and throughout the house is just not making sense.

Economics plays a big role in this argument plus safety of course.

Comment: Power lines have high voltage, low current because current and wire size are directly proportional.  Thick copper/aluminum cables to carry the necessary current to houses would become too heavy and cumbersome after only a few miles out.  This makes high voltage, low current efficient in practice. Efficiency and economy have a direct relationship except when there are lags in innovation. Consider the history of solar power...